# Error starting symfony project (syntax error near unexpected token `newline'). Could it be php version incompatibility?

Tags: php, centos, redhat, symfony-2.7

Error when I try start the local server:
[image_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghm7r.png)

```
/usr/local/bin/symfony: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/usr/local/bin/symfony: line 1: `<!DOCTYPE html>'
```

Composer.json requires:

```
"require" : {
    "php" : ">=5.4.16",
    "symfony/symfony" : "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm" : "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal" : "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "~1.4",
    "twig/extensions" : "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle" : "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle" : "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle" : "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle" : "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle" : "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler" : "~2.0",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle" : "0.3.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "~2.0@dev",
    "guilhermednt/hwi-oauth-proxy-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "jms/serializer-bundle" : "*",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle" : "~2.4",
    "sensio/buzz-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle" : "1.7.*",
    "guilhermednt/buzz-proxied-curl-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle" : "*@dev",
    "ramsey/uuid" : "~2.8",
    "oro/doctrine-extensions" : "^1.0",
    "nelmio/cors-bundle" : "^1.4",
    "jumbojett/openid-connect-php" : "^0.3.0",
    "becklyn/static-roles-bundle" : "@dev",
    "phpunit/phpunit" : "^4.8",
    "ci/restclientbundle" : "^2.0",
    "ejsmont-artur/php-circuit-breaker-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "liip/monitor-bundle" : "^2.2"
},
```

Could it be php version incompatibility? I'm using CentOS7 but I have little experience with it and I never used symfony.

I didn't find anything in other answers